# EventBus: @Subscribe - not receive message

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

Here my frament subscriber:

```
public class FragmentSort extends Fragment {

@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
}


 @Subscribe
    public void onChangeFilter(Integer categoryId) {
      // NOT CALL
    }
```

Here my main frament that send message:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private void searchViewPostAction(Integer categoryId) {
        searchView.clearFocus();
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new CategoryFilterEvent(categoryId));
    }
}
```

Here my POJO:

```
public class CategoryFilterEvent {
    private Integer categoryId;

    public CategoryFilterEvent(Integer categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

}
```

Method `MainFragment.searchViewPostAction()` is call but message not receive.
Method `FragmentSort.onChangeFilter()` is **NOT** call.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a getter method to `CategoryFilterEvent`

```
public int getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}
```

And change:

```
@Subscribe
public void onChangeFilter(Integer categoryId) {
  // NOT CALL
}
```

to:

```
@Subscribe
public void onChangeFilter(CategoryFilterEvent event) {
  // THIS WILL BE CALLED
    int categoryId = event.getCategoryId();
}
```